# Do we have $\Lambda^2(V \otimes V') = \Lambda^2 V \oplus V \otimes V' \oplus \Lambda^2 V'$?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

Let $V, V'$ be two finite dimensional vector spaces. Do we have $\Lambda^2(V \otimes V') = \Lambda^2 V \oplus V \otimes V' \oplus \Lambda^2 V'$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Nope. Suppose $V,V'$ are both $1$-dimensional. Then the LHS is $0$, but the $V\otimes V'$ term survives on the RHS.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/77948/an-isomorphism-of-2-schur-modules?rq=1 for something that does hold for the 2nd exterior power of a tensor product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\Lambda^2(V \otimes V') = (\Lambda^2 V \otimes S^2 V') \oplus (S^2 V \otimes  \Lambda^2 V')$.

Edit: It is clear that the two summands of the right hand side are sub-spaces of $\Lambda^2(V \otimes V')$. Moreover, the dimension of the left hand side equals to the dimension of the right hand side.

Comment: It may not be entirely clear to all of us how your answer contributes to the original question. Could you elaborate a little?